# Database Structure that has the same table structure with different table names

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, xamarin

The application i am creating will hold multiple pages which will hold different values depending on user input. For Example 1 book will have 10 pages, the table names will be Book1_p1, Book1_p2, Book1_p3, Book1_p4, etc. This database will be the same structure just different table names, is this good practise or to have one table called pages, my only concern is this will gather a lot of rows over time. See below an example of the structure.

```
    id | Page ID     | Field Id | Value
    ------------------------------------
     1 | 1           | 5        | hello
     2 | 1           | 3        | some info 
     3 | 1           | 2        | fdf
     4 | 1           | 1
     5 | 1           | 3
     6 | 1           | 2
     7 | 1           | 1
     8 | 1           | 3
     9 | 1           | 2
    10 | 1           | 1
    11 | 1           | 2
    12 | 1           | 1
```

I am using SQLite in Xamarin. I have used this before and creating a table from a class with `database.CreateTable<BookTable>();`

**BookTable Class**

```
 public class BookTable
    {
        public BookTable()
        {

        }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

From research it is not possible to use the same class with different table names as the class name is used for the table name, You never know i might be wrong. Is this a good approach or am i going to get come across problems when the database grows.

Comment: Your database structure is dependent on the relationships between the data elements.  You really shouldn't base it on the pages.

Comment: As Raj mentions, you want this to be as Relational as possible and not depend upon one type of object. It might be a good idea to pick up a Relational Database Standards book and go through a few concepts inside.

Comment: @RajMore Thanks for your input, i am just trying to make it future proof as well. For example more books are added. So you think having a pages table that will contain all of the page records would be the best approach.

Comment: @jonDouglas Thanks, i am going to do a bit more studying before i make my decision, just dont want to get 1-2 years down the line and realise i could of done it better another way. :)

Answer (score 1):

If every Book will have the same table structure, then you should really place them all in a single Book table.

Comment: Okay, what will happen to performance if each book will generate between 250-500 rows and there could be over 1,000 books in time.

Comment: You'll have to test to determine if performance is an issue, but 500k rows is not really that big, and it looks like each individual row should be fairly small.